# Stop indenting second blank line after end of the list

Tags: org-mode

I try to configure org mode in the way that it doesn't indent second blank line after last item of the list. Is there a way to achieve this?

Example:

```
- All of the words in Lorem Ipsum have flirted with me - consciously or unconsciously.
- That's to be expected.

  <this is still indented by default, I try to make it unindented by default>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's part of the syntax. The [syntax document](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html#Plain_Lists_and_Items) says: `An item ends before the next item, the first line less or equally indented than its starting line, or two consecutive empty lines.... A plain list is a set of consecutive items of the same indentation. It can only directly contain items.` So you need two consecutive empty lines to finish an item (and therefore the containing list). That allows items to be separated by a single empty line (which is useful for readability).

Comment: Isn't that customizable via `org-list-end-re`?

Comment: That's meant to be a constant (it is defined via `defconst`), so no. Changing it will break things.

Comment: Ok thanks for explaining that.